# C# Trim string regardless of characters

Tags: c#

So here the situation.

I have multiple strings that begin and end with a random amount of spaces.  The problem is the string contains multiple words so I can't just replace(" ","") so for example.

```
"       apple red "
'   orange orange   '  
'  pear grapes  '  
'                   turnship turn it over here '
```

and I would want to return.
    'apple red'
    'orange orange'
    'pear grapes'
    'turnship turn it over here '

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about String.Trim()?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx

Returns a new string in which all **leading** and **trailing** occurrences of a set of specified characters from the current String object are removed.

Comment: Ooo an easy comment, not use to it TY.

Answer (score 1):

Try

yourString.Trim();

> Removes all occurrences of white space
>   characters from the beginning and end
>   of this instance.
>
> [Visual Basic] Overloads Public
>   Function Trim() As String [C#] public
>   string Trim(); [C++] public: String*
>   Trim(); [JScript] public function
>   Trim() : String; Return Value
>
> A new String equivalent to this
>   instance after white space characters
>   are removed from the beginning and
>   end.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904317(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @OlimpiuPOP Did you accidentally mean to post elsewhere? Otherwise, this is the method and link to the documentation that does exactly what was asked for.

Comment: you should've use the typing to improve the content of the response. An example how he can use the trim method etc....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the quotes are really in there, then you want to use a regular expression:

```
(["'])\s*(.*[^\s])\s*(["'])
```

Simply replace it with:

```
$1$2$3
```

So:

```
string value = Regex.Replace("\"   value to trim   \"", @"([""'])\s*(.*[^\s])\s*([""'])", "$1$2$3");
```

Comment: For whomever downvoted me: there are different quotes in the strings in the question and that is clearly stated in my answer with the assumption in the first sentence.

Comment: Regular expressions are completely overkill for this problem.  Even if the quotes were part of the string and needed to be stripped, calling `myString.Trim(' ', '\'', '"')` would trim the string while being easy to read and very likely more efficient.

Comment: @Chris The above regular expression keeps the quotes in tact, as his list of "returned" strings contained the quotes. Your solution would remove the quotes.